# цикл выводит только последний елемент таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, sql, веб-программирование, mysqli

столкнулся с проблемой что цикл выводит только последний елемент таблицы, не могу понять где пропустил итерацию

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', 'Admin', 'novartis');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
  echo "Извините возникла проблема на сайте";
  echo "Ошибка: Не удалось создать соединение с базой MySQL и вот почему: \n";
  echo "Номер ошибки:".$mysqli->connect_errno."\n";
  echo "Ошибка:".$mysqli->connect_error."\n";
  exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `sandoz`";
if (!$run = $mysqli->query($sql))
{
  echo "Извините, возникла проблема в работе сайта";
  echo "Ошибка: Наш запрос не удался и вот почему: \n";
  echo "Запрос:".$sql."\n";
  echo "Номер_ошибки".$mysqli->errno."\n";
  echo "Ошибка:".$mysqli->error."\n";
  exit;
}
$result = array();
if ($run && mysqli_num_rows($run) !=0)
{
  while ($rs = $run->fetch_assoc())
   {
    $result[] = $rs;
   }
}

foreach($result as $key=>$val)
{
  $data = '<tr>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Inventory_LLC'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Inventory_DD'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['AssetCategory'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['AssetType'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['AssetSubtype'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Transfer_Date'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Return_Date'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['UniqID'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Asset_Owner'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Owner_Comp'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Owner_Location'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Owner_Status'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Asset_Status'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Asset_Entry'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['SN'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Notes'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['CR_IMEI'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Org_Unit'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Position'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Cost'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Any_Val'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Pur_Date'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Check_Uncheck'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Local_Material'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['PO'].'</td>';
  $data .= '<td>'.$val['Activated'].'</td>';
  $data .= '</tr>';
}
 ?>

 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Inventory_LLC</th>
      <th>Inventory_DD</th>
      <th>AssetCategory</th>
      <th>AssetType</th>
      <th>AssetSubtype</th>
      <th>Transfer_Date</th>
      <th>Return_Date</th>
      <th>UniqID</th>
      <th>Asset_Owner</th>
      <th>Owner_Comp</th>
      <th>Owner_Location</th>
      <th>Owner_Status</th>
      <th>Asset_Status</th>
      <th>Asset_Entry</th>
      <th>SN</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
      <th>CR_IMEI</th>
      <th>Org_Unit</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Any_Val</th>
      <th>Pur_Date</th>
      <th>Check_Uncheck</th>
      <th>Local_Material</th>
      <th>PO</th>
      <th>Activated</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?=$data?>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: А зачем вообще использовать 2 цикла, когда можно сделать одним `while`? И зачем столько `$data.=` делать? Когда можно одну.. Непонятно.

Comment: `$data = '<tr>';` при таком начале каждой итерации без конкатенации не удивительно. что вы получаете только последнюю строку.

Comment: с одним $data.= некоректно отображается хз почему, а 2 цикла для заполнения и перебора

Comment: teran, спасибо, невнимательность наше все)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в теле цикла foreach пропустил точку в первом выводе $data = , должно быть $data .=